# Can't start HAProxy on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, haproxy

I'm trying to start up HAProxy on Cygwin.  When I do so, I get the following response:

```
$ /usr/local/sbin/haproxy -f /usr/local/sbin/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 313/180006 (4008) : cannot change UNIX socket ownership 
                           (/tmp/haproxy.socket). Aborting.
[ALERT] 313/180006 (4008) : [/usr/local/sbin/haproxy.main()] 
                            Some protocols failed to start 
                            their listeners! Exiting.
```

It looks like it's due to the following line in my config file, when I rip this it starts up:

```
stats socket /tmp/haproxy.socket uid haproxy mode 770 level admin
```

The entire config:

```
global
log 127.0.0.1 local0 info
stats socket /tmp/haproxy.socket uid haproxy mode 770 level admin
maxconn 1000
daemon

defaults
log global
mode tcp
option tcplog
option dontlognull
retries 3
option redispatch
maxconn 1000
timeout connect 5s
timeout client 120s
timeout server 120s

listen rabbitmq_local_cluster 127.0.0.1:5555
mode tcp
balance roundrobin
server rabbit_0 127.0.0.1:5673 check inter 5000 rise 2 fall 3
server rabbit_1 127.0.0.1:5674 check inter 5000 rise 2 fall 3

listen private_monitoring 127.0.0.1:8100
mode http
option httplog
stats enable
stats uri /stats
stats refresh 5s
```

Any ideas would be appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, as I expected.  My user "haproxy" which is referenced in the problematic line:

stats socket /tmp/haproxy.socket uid **haproxy** mode 770 level admin

Did not have necessary permissions on the local machine.  Once this was set up, it started up fine.

Answer (score 1):

Nice to know that it still works on cygwin, what version of haproxy is this ? I did not know that UNIX sockets were supported on windows BTW. Or maybe they're emulated via named pipes ?

Comment: Hi @Willy Tarreau, it's HAP 1.4.22.  Not sure on the Unix sockets question as I know very little on the subject (hence the noob question).  I was just trying to get a local LB set up to test out RabbitMQ clustering and Cygwin/HAP combo was recommended as a relatively easy solution to set up.  The config I used was primarily a cut and paste from an example.  If you have any knowledge to impart on the subject, it would be appreciated.  Thanks!